# PHP framework or app for customer support / automated troubleshooting

Tags: php, customer-service

I need to provide my customers a web help so that I can diagnose their issues. I was thinking about a tree questionnaire, where the leaf is either the response to the issue, or a "Please call the support team".

I was wondering if there were builtin solutions as PhpBB is for forums ?

Thanks in advance !

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I can't think of any off-hand, but it seems like what you want is a [knowledgebase](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Knowledgebase) or [expert system](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Expert_system). This is a very active area of research and software development, and you should be able to find many open source solutions (many developed by academia).

These allow users to troubleshoot their own problems. For instance, you could have an expert system that allows users to diagnose their own illness based on filling out a questionnaire of their symptons.

Comment: Googling with "expert system" lead me to http://code.google.com/p/interactive-decision-tree/. I'll dig further and see if I can find better stuff ! Thank you for these keywords !